# jquery textbox value returned is not the value in the textbox

Tags: jquery, textbox

I'm using jquery to get value of textbox, and instead of returning the value in the textbox,
i get the below code. Not sure if this makes a difference, but textbox value is set after page is loaded.

```
function (a) {
    var c, d, e, g = this[0]; {
        if ( !! arguments.length) {
            e = f.isFunction(a);
            return this.each(function (d) {
                var g = f(this),
                    h;
                if (this.nodeType === 1) {
                    e ? h = a.call(this, d, g.val()) : h = a, h == null ? h = "" : typeof h == "number" ? h += "" : f.isArray(h) && (h = f.map(h, function (a) {
                        return a == null ? "" : a + ""
                    })), c = f.valHooks[this.type] || f.valHooks[this.nodeName.toLowerCase()];
                    if (!c || !("set" in c) || c.set(this, h, "value") === b) this.value = h
                }
            })
        }
        if (g) {
            c = f.valHooks[g.type] || f.valHooks[g.nodeName.toLowerCase()];
            if (c && "get" in c && (d = c.get(g, "value")) !== b) return d;
            d = g.value;
            return typeof d == "string" ? d.replace(q, "") : d == null ? "" : d
        }
    }
}
```

here  is the jquery code

```
input = "#OperatorUpdateEmployeeNum";
  $(input).blur(function(){

    alert($("#OperatorUpdateEmployeeNum").val);
}
```

Does anyone know why its not giving the actual value in the textbox?
thanks.

Comment: `.val` is a function you need to use `.val()`, what you are getting is the text that makes up the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of something, you should use the method

```
val()
```

So you code might be:

```
alert($("#OperatorUpdateEmployeeNum").val());
```

If your text value is loaded on the page end you should use the event "onload" from document. With jquery its like that:

```
$(function(){
//now create your event listener
 $(input).blur(function(){    
    // on this case you case use $(this) becouse "this" pointing to selector of the event
    alert($(this).val());
}
});
```

Comment: thank you that guys, that worked. I should have double checked that :/